# How do I switch between windows on one desktop on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gnome-shell, workspaces, application-switcher

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 and find in very inconvenient: <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> (switch between applications) can bring you to a different desktop.

Usually I keep windows related to different activities on different desktops, e.g. the git desktop (some terminal windows and a text editor, sometimes gitk), the remote server desktop (two terminals with ssh, Firefox with a page from that server, and a text editor), the corporative mail desktop (Firefox with e-mail web interface, Skype, one more text editor), the source code desktop (IDE, some terminal shells and a text editor), etc.

In other words, Terminal and Gedit have many windows on different desktops, and these windows are unrelated, so grouping windows by application does not work.

***How do I switch between windows on the current workspace?***

Answer (score 1):

Install Tweaks and shell extensions by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks gnome-shell-extensions
```

Then open Tweaks and go to Extensions:
enable Alternatetab, customize it: tick **Show only windows in the current workspace**.

Comment: Without installing anything, you could also run: `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.window-switcher current-workspace-only true`

Comment: @jacob But that won't disable the '*grouping windows by application*' feature, which is something OP doesn't want either (OP wants to switch *windows*). So for that reason this answer looks more useful to this specific question.

Comment: @pomsky what gnome-tweaks does is exactly change the gsettings value I mentioned. Try running `dconf watch /` and make the change in gnome-tweaks.

Comment: @jacob I think you have overlooked the "installing `gnome-shell-extensions` and enabling Alternatetab" part from the answer. Seems like OP wants both the following: *switching between windows* (as opposed to grouped-windows of the same application) and *isolating workspaces*. The `gsettings` command achieves the second part, whereas this answer deals with both in one go.

Comment: @pomsky ah, wait, you're right. skimmed gnome-tweaks, missed the rest of the line.